# Reset the scope using an onclick event with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a scope variable that gets set when a user clicks an element. I would simply like to change that variable to false when a user clicks outside the element. Common convention for modals or popup menus.

I have a plunker demonstrating my code and the problem. It's based off another plunker I started so it may seem extraneous but it is indicative of my exact issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/O7YwaPci894XjX7XgsGe?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [ng-focus](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angFocus) and a [ng-blur directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBlur) to the element.

In order to use these directives on elements different than `input, select, textarea, a` first add a [tabindex attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/tabindex-focus) to the element:

```
<p tabindex="0" data-ng-focus="setScopeVariable()" data-ng-blur="resetScopeVariable()">Click me!</p>
```

Comment: Never would have considered using focus/blur. Nice one. Couldn't get it to work in Plunker so I was going to give up on it but it works fine in my build. Doesn't quite solve my specific problem but it certainly answers the question.